# Знаки препинания, двоеточие

Tags: пунктуация

Размер: высота: 52 см, ширина: 15 см, длина: 8 см. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 3):

Размеры: высота - 52 см, ширина - 15 см, длина - 8 см . Или можно не ставить тире в специальной литературе.

**Примеры:**

1) Длина Волги – 3688 километров.

2) В специальной литературе (тире не ставится):

Максимальная дальность действия прибора два километра.
Стоимость товара пять тысяч рублей.
Температура плавления золота 1063 градуса.

Answer (score 1):

В специальной литературе, как уже сказали, тире может не ставиться, поэтому предлагаю такой вариант оформления.

```
Размер: высота 52 см, ширина 15 см, длина 8 см.
```